# Android arm emulator has no network access

Tags: android-emulator

I'm struggling with Android emulator version 26.0.0.0. The tools are managed by the Android Studio (2.3.1). All this running on Fedora FC25 with latest updates.

I can't seem to get the ARM emulator to have network access. Same works fine with x86/x64, but not arm (or arm64).

It looks like I ran to the end of my abilities to debug what's going on, and on where to continue digging.

**On arm** : no ability to resolve names, no ability to connect to the outside network. I'm running `nc` from `adb shell` to check the connectivity. On an arm emulator, I get timeout on host lookup when using host name, and `no route to host` when attempting to connect by IP. Browser application also can't connect. I run `strace` on the emulator and I don't even see attempts to connect to the DNS server.

**On x86** : everything works. However I did have to add `-dns-server` option before it started working.

**Debugging** The most I did was running strace for both the emulators and examining the difference. AFAIU, there is an I/O thread that gets to make the requests, and it looks like it's not picking up the requests in arm case. Or the requests are not properly deposited. The thread seems to be OK otherwise, it iterates between polls and futex locks.

Of course, my whole point is to run ARM emulators (needed to debug certain ARM native code).

Debug outputs (I did remove multi-touch connection errors from the output):

- [arm](https://pastebin.com/qzJu4yNy)
- [x86](https://pastebin.com/Yw5b0YbR)

Any pointers on where to dig, or what I may be doing wrong is greatly appreciated. I can post full trace files from running both as well.

Answer (score 0):

update your Android emulator to v26.1.0, it will work fine.